# Best way to compress JS array of objects before putting into MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, compression

I have large arrays of objects, near 2 Mb per each array. Currently I store this array as it is in MongoDB document.

How can I compress it, for example into string to reduce size of this object, and consequently reduce MongoDB Disk usage?

Comment: You can specify the algorithm that the WiredTiger storage engine uses to compress documents on disk. It defaults to Snappy, which is a good fit for most workloads (it's quick, does good enough compression, and is light on the CPU).

Comment: Thanks, @willis, but I need to compress just part of each document, rest must be the same

Comment: I'm saying that if you're using WiredTiger (which if you're on Mongo 3.2 or above, you likely are), it's _already_ compressed on disk and you can change the algorithm that WiredTiger uses to do that compression. You can see the different compression options available in http://source.wiredtiger.com/mongodb-3.4/tune_page_size_and_comp.html

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if strings are more compressible than objects, so if you change that array into a string, it'd likely take up less space on disk. But, you'll be paying an extra cost to parse that document, and not being able to use mongo operations on that array seems like a real bummer to me

Comment: @willis thanks! for now we get warning from MongoDB Atlas: Disk I/O % utilization on Data Partition has gone above 70 on nvme2n1 
I want to find any approaches to avoid this problem. Because when I need to read just few fields of document,  MongoDB "raise" whole document from disc.

Comment: If you don't need the full document, you could look into creating an index that can "cover" the query. If that's not possible, it might be worth separating your data into two different collections or changing the schema in another way.